# raspberry pi interfacing with ds18b20

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I have been working on a home automation project using raspberry pi. I need to import module 
**W1thermsensor** for communicating with ds18b20. Our modules are currently written in python 2.7 and ds18b20 is written in python 3.3.

Is there an alternative for ds18b20 in python 2.7?

Porting code from python 2.7 to 3.3 is not an option due to deadlines.

Comment: when you install w1thermsensor you are using pip3 ? If yes you can try install the module using python 2.7 pip "pip install w1thermsensor"

Answer (score 2):

From official [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/w1thermsensor/):

For Python3: `sudo apt-get install python3-w1thermsensor`

For Python2: `sudo apt-get install python-w1thermsensor`